# How would one go about creating a custom TFX component to perform feature engineering/building

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfx

TFX Transform component operates with Tensors that cannot be executed eagerly within its *preprocessing_fn*. Therefore the values for each feature cannot be passed to a python function that generates new features based on those values.

I tried creating a custom component but failed to modify the input data as *tf.Example* objects can't be modified.

What is the recommended way to construct complex/custom features from within the pipeline?

Comment: Please check this link and explore :- https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/workshops/blob/master/tfx_labs/Lab_8_Custom_Components.ipynb